# Bose Einstein Condensate

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Bose Einstein condensate photons stop moving, but with reference to what frame of reference? Photons move at constant speed in all reference frames so what happens to Maxwell equations at zero degree kelvin?

Answer (score 4):

In a Bose-Einstein condensate the electrical field of the light interacts with the condensate and the photons and the condensate become entangled. Once this happens the light forms a quasiparticle called a [polariton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton). The velocity is no longer the velocity of the photon but instead it is the velocity of the polariton. The polariton behaves like a massive particle and therefore it moves at speeds less than $c$.

The speed referred to in these experiments is the speed measured in the rest frame of the condensate, which is generally the laboratory frame since the condensate is usually at rest in the laboratory.

It sounds very odd that in these experiments the speed of light can be reduced to a few metres per second, but the underlying principle is really no different from the slowing of light that occurs in media like glass or water. In both cases it is the interaction between the photons and the medium that causes the slowing. It's just that in a BEC the interaction is many orders of magnitude stronger than in e.g. glass so the slowing is much more drastic.